# My CloudKit app made with swift4/xcode10 work only in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I try to save and retrieve an array from iCloud. Then, i want to print result and display the result in a label.

In simulator, the result is printed instantly but the text in the label is just show after aprox 15 seconds, don't understand why i got this delay!

Anyway, my code work in the simulator (or in a device linked directly to Xcode) but when i send the app to "testflight" and download it from there it no longer display the result in my label.

My testers have try it on different device, with no result: nothing is show in the label after app is sent to test flight

```
 import UIKit
 import CloudKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

    struct Structure: Codable {
        var a, b, c, d : String
        var e : Double
    }


    var var1 = [
        Structure(a: "-1", b: "111", c: "aaa", d: "2017-01-21 05:55:55", e: 1),
        Structure(a: "111.1", b: "-1", c: "AAAAAA", d: "2018-04-27 07:54:25", e: 11)]

    var var2 = [
        Structure(a: "", b: "", c: "", d: "", e: 0),
        Structure(a: "", b: "", c: "", d: "", e: 0)]


    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!


    @IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {
        // Delete old record
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Structure", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, error) in

            if error == nil {
                for record in records! {
                    CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.delete(withRecordID: record.recordID, completionHandler: { (recordId, error) in })
                }
                print("Deleted record")
            }
        }

        // Save var1
        let myRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Structure")
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(var1) {
            myRecord["Content1"] = data
        }
        CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.save(myRecord) { (record, error) in
            guard record != nil else { return }
            print("saved var1")
        }
    }




    @IBAction func Load(_ sender: Any) {

        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Structure", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))

        CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, error) in
            records?.forEach({ (record) in

                let content = record.value(forKey: "Content1")

                //convert data to var2
                if let lp = content as? Data{
                    if let valuefromicloud = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Array.self, from: lp) as [Structure]{
                        self.var2 = valuefromicloud
                    }
                }
                //The next line print result instantly
                print("Data from iCloud: \(self.var2[0].b)")

                //The next line show result after aprox 15 sec delay, why this delay???
                self.Label.text =  "Data from iCloud: \(self.var2[0].b)"
            })
        }}
 }
```

So, i have three questions:

1: Why does result is printed instantly, but label need aprox 15 sec to be updated in simulator?

2: Why does my app no longer update his label after my testers download it from test flight?

3: Can you give me an exemple of a working code that save/retreive my array from iCloud?

Comment: All UI updates must be done on the main queue. CloudKit completion handlers are always called on a background queue.

Comment: Did you use the CloudKit dashboard to move your development CloudKit environment to production?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry, but i'm a beginer with xcode, and i dont know what you mean by : "move your development CloudKit environment to production"? The only thing i have done is put this code in my xcode, archive and send to appstore, then i load the app through test flight and its no longer working when it was working before directly in simulator